# Passing Array to controller for saving in many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I am trying to allow my users to add tags to submitted job postings.

To do this, I am using the bootstrap-tokenfield plugin.

Jquery script to gather array and submit:

```
    //create a new array and push the skills on to it. 
    var tokenfield = new Array();
      $(".skills").each(function() {
      tokenfield.push($(this).val());
      });
```

This is then submitted to my controller function along with all of the form details using ajax.

controller:

```
    //save job
      $job = new Job;
      $job->user_id = $this->userID;
    //other fields...
      $job->save();

//After job is saved iterate over tokenfield array and save to pivot table using Laravel Eloquent properties:

    foreach($_POST['tokenfield'] as $val){
        //only skill name is passed from form.  Find id:
    $skill = Skill::where('name','=', $val)->first();
    if(JobSkill::create(array('job_id' => $job->id, 'skill_id' => $skill->id)))
            { return Response::json(array('success' => 200));}
```

I am getting the error: attempting to get property of non-object related to $skill->id so I did a dd($_POST['tokenfield']);  and this was the result:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(33) "Window Installation, deck removal"}
```

My question is:  Am I not creating the array properly or am I not accepting it properly in the controller?   TIA

Answer (score 0):

Simply Put Laravel is not accepting $_POST['tokenfield']

not so great at JAVA but

```
    var tokenfield = new Array();
  $(".skills").each(function() {
  tokenfield.push($(this).val());
  });
```

aint this meant to be

```
    var tokenfield = new Array(
  $(".skills").each(function() {
  tokenfield.push($(this).val());
  }));
```

correct me if i am wrong but to me this looks like that the controller cant find the post data